# Vue project (django + webpack) shows white screen when accessing ngrok on mobile

Tags: vue.js, ngrok

I'm trying to use ngrok to test my vue + django project on my mobile phone, and it isn't working (it just shows a white screen). The vue portion is served using webpack (v2, not the latest vue cli 3).

The funny thing is ngrok works when I access my vue project from my computer (or another colleague's computer) - it just doesn't work from a mobile phone. The http log shows a 200 response, just that it shows a white screen on my phone. In addition, accessing other none vue pages work, so it's probably a webpack issue.

I've tried setting `disableHostCheck` to true, but it still doesn't work, and I'm not sure what else to do.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({
      filename: 'webpack-stats.json'
    }),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true,
    // security risk to set to true, but need to turn it on for ngrok to work
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hot: true,
  },
}
```

settings.py (django)

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'webpack_bundles/', # must end with slash
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(str(BASE_DIR), 'frontend', 'webpack-stats.json'),
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map']
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't specify what mobile OS or which browser, but you can enable remote debugging in [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) or [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE) which could help you out to track down the errors.

Comment: Ah, the problem is with ios devices. Does it work with chrome as well?